# Want a better user experience than opening popups on click

Tags: usability

I want a better user experience rather then opening popups on click of "Assign Group", "Switch Group" and the "Author" link. 
I also want to avoid inline grid editing due to maintenance issues.
Can anyone suggest a better want of doing this?

Please have a look at the screenshot uploaded.

Thanks so much! 
Roland[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think pop-ups are poorer UX?

Comment: Because they can be blocked on the users machine

Comment: You can easily use a modal instead of actually opening a completely new window.  Modals can't be blocked and offer a very good UX.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Using a modal at the moment but still to simplify the operation wanted to do away with the popup since there are not many fields on it.

Answer (score 3):

Not using overlays/popups does not by default result in a better user experience. I don't know exactly what you will be able to do when you click on **Assign Group** and thus I don't know if my answer will be relevant to you.

One way to approach your problem would be to use dropdown buttons. You can do alot with these kinds of buttons and if you have many groups you can add a search field in there as well the help the user find the correct groups fast.

[image: Button dropdowns]

You can find many good examples here: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/definition

Lastly: I highly recommend reading this article from Nielsen Norman Group about **Overuse of Overlays: How to Avoid Misusing Lightboxes**: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/overuse-of-overlays/

Comment: Thanks for reaching out and sharing the links. I have uploaded the popup screenshot

Comment: @Rolz No worries. Just by looking at your modal I feel the answer I gave could be the right way to approach your problem. I see no point in displaying the users you have already selected twice. Best of luck to you!